# Multi step form, custom plugin

Tags: plugins, php, forms

I have built a working multi-page contact form that has Zoho CRM & Slack integration.

What I want to do is when a user goes to our contact page, they will see the first half of the form (step1.php) then depending on the job that they want us to do (branding, web, video) step2.php will open up, then lastly a "thank you" message on step3.php.

At the moment step1's form has this:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo plugins_url('step2.php',__FILE__)?>">
```

which echo's in the browser as:

http://localhost/COMPANY/wp-content/plugins/COMPANY-contact/step2.php

I do not want this url to show up, instead I want the URL to look like (or similar)

http://localhost/COMPANY/step2

Lastly, because it's echoing directly to the plugin's folder it does not allow me to use get_head / get_footer so I cannot apply my website's theme, which is what I want too!

Comment: Is this for a personal site, or is the plugin intended for distribution? Basically, your forms should be rendered in WordPress pages, and the actions should point to WordPress URLs.

Comment: @Milo Personal website (it's for the company I work at) so it's not intended for distribution

Answer (score 2):

The process can be done by posting the form to the current page, and then using those values from the `$_POST` object to determine the next form.

In the simplest example, a hidden input named "page" can increase its value on each step. Set the value of additional hidden inputs with the data from `$_POST` if it is needed in later steps/forms.

The sample method below does this. I added a shortcode, `[count_page_form]` that can include it in a post or page so it's easy to test.  All of this would go in theme's *functions.php*

(*don't use in production, obviously, no sanitization or validation being done here*).

It should be enough of an example for you to modify what you have working.

### Example:

```
add_shortcode('count_page_form','count_page_function');

function count_page_function(){
    global $wpdb;
    $current_page  =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    //check for $_POST value for our page_count, make it null if it isn't there since that means we're on page 1
    if ($_POST && $_POST['page']) { 
        $page_count   =   $_POST['page'];
    }
    else { 
        $page_count = null; 
    }
    //now let's start checking the page_count and displaying as needed
    if ( $page_count == NULL ) {
        echo '<form method="post" action="' . $current_page .'">
                <label for="first_name" id="first_name">First Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />

                <input type="hidden" value="1" name="page" />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>';
            //the hidden input type above gives our $_POST['page'] a value of one upon submission
    }//end page 1
    elseif ( $page_count == 1 ) {
        //grab values from first $_POST, we will add them to hidden input below so new $_POST has them  
        $first_name =   $_POST['first_name'];

        echo '<h2>This is page two</h2>';
        // note below we add the hidden for first_name, and we change the value for page to 2
        echo '<form method="post" action="' . $current_page .'">
            <input type="hidden" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="'. $first_name .'" />
            <label for="second_name" id="second_name">Second Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="second_name" id="second_name" />
            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="page" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>';

    }//end page 2
    elseif ($page_count == 2) {
        $first_name  = $_POST['first_name'];
        $second_name = $_POST['second_name'];

        echo '<h2>The third page!</h2>';
        echo $second_name;
        echo $first_name;
    }//end page 3
}//end count_page_function
```